# 64-bit SQL Server Linked server to SyBase via 32-bit ODBC driver

Tags: sql-server, odbc, sybase, 32bit-64bit, linked-server

What I have:

- a 64-bit SQL Server 2012 installed on Windows Server 2008R2
- 32-bit ODBC driver SyBase ASE 12.5.1 (and I have no ability to obtain any other official driver)

What I need:

- access from SQL Server to SyBase `Adaptive Server Enterprise/12.5.4/EBF 14921 ESD#7/P/RS6000/AIX 5.1/ase1254/2095/64-bit/FBO/Fri Oct 12 12:11:32 2007` (I need to select data from 2 tables and to execute 2 stored procedures)

I've installed the ODBC driver and created an ODBC source using `c:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe`. A connection is successfully established when I test it from ODBC Data Source Administrator. But when I create a linked server I get an error:

> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application".

That's because there is a mismatch between 64-bit SQL Server and 32-bit ODBC driver.
And obviously I need some proxy to provide connection between server and driver.
I've found a few bridges but all of them are proprietary.

Is there any free proxy solution or a free 64-bit SyBase driver?

**UPD**

There is still no good production solution, but as proposed Paolo in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32778758/5308054), I use a 32-bit SQL Server Express to resolve the issue.

What I've done step by step:

1. install a 32-bit SQL Server Express 2014 on the same
   copmputer (probably it is not the best idea, but it makes possible
   to use `Shared Memory` )
2. connect the 32-bit SQL Server Express to the Sybase database via ODBC
3. create stored procedures on Express using the `OPENQUERY` function to request data from SyBase
4. connect the 32-bit SQL Server Express 2014 to the 64-bit SQL Sever 2012 as a linked server (address of Express is `LOCAL\(SQLEXPRESS)`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

install a spare sql server express 32 bit (i would put it on a separate machine) as a bridge to sybase.

on the 64bit instance create a linked server to the 32bit instance; on the 32bit instance create a linked server to sybase.

i didn't try this double hop configuration but it may eventually require some view on the 32bit rdbms to access the data on sybase from the 64bit instance.

it is not a solution i would like to have in production for a long time...

Comment: Thank you Paolo! Does it matter to install express on a separate machine or on the same?

Comment: i know for sure you can have different version AND different bitness (sql 2012x64 and sql 2014x86) on the same machine; never tried to install same version different bitness. whenever i can i prefer to have a separate machine.

Comment: I've installed a 32bit SQL Server Express 2014, then connected it to the SyBase  database via ODBC and made SQL Server stored procedures with `OPENQUERY` inside. Then I made a linked server connection from the main SQL Server 64 to the SQL Sever Express 32 using only `Shared Memory`. And now I'm able to request data from SyBase on my 64-bit SQL Server.

Comment: @DmitryPolyakov feel free to mark my post as answer ^^

Comment: Probably, there won't be any better issue resolution.

Comment: @DmitryPolyakov other option actually exists but requires third party tools as the odbc-odbc bridge (a commercial software, the first pick from google). if your budget allows for it you can give it a try.